# modification time of file in future, but timezone is set correctly

Tags: unix, solaris, time, date

Files that I am creating at a Unix server are created with a modification time that lies 5 days in future. But when I check with the date command, it seems, that timezone and date are set correctly. :

```
# uname -a
SunOS tmxd050a 5.10 Generic_118833-33 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-T1000 Solaris
tst@server : /home/tst/test
# date
Tue Jul 12 08:31:09 CEST 2011
tst@server : /home/tst/test
# touch test_file
tst@server : /home/tst/test
# ls -al test_file
-rw-r--r-- 1 dbx dbx 0 Jul 19  2011 test_file
tst@server : /home/tst/test
```

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that /home/tst was mounted on another server which had an incorrect timezone setting.